# Show that a Sequence is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N  |a_n - a_{n+1}| \lt \infty$. Show $a_n$ is Cauchy.

My work:
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_1^N |a_n - a_{n+1}| = |a_1 - a_2| + \cdots+|a_{N-1} - a_N| \ge |a_1| + |a_3|+\cdots+ |a_{2n+1}|$$ for $n \ge 1$ 
Therefore since $\infty \gt \sum_1^N  |a_n - a_{n+1}| \ge \sum_1^{2n+1} |a_n|$ and |$a_n$| is positive, it is finite. Therefore the subsequence of $|a_n|$ for odd positive integers converges, so by Bolzano-Weierstraß theorem, the sequence is bounded, therefore the sequence is cauchy.

Comment: I think you're missing something...$a_n$ is a sequence such that the stated limit is finite, or...?

Comment: ...such that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n-a_{n+1}|$...what?.. exists?

Comment: Your inequality isn't true if we let $a_n=1$ for all $n$. That is, where you say $\sum |a_n-a_{n+1}|\geq\sum |a_{2n-1}|$.

Comment: It is good that you show your own work, but it is full of mistakes. Not to mention that those guys were not called Balzano and Wierstrauss.

Comment: @Clayton im confused, |$a_n - a_{n+1}| \ge |a_n| - |a_{n+1}|$ so souldnt the equality hold for the sum? pardon my noobness

Comment: @TMM Comment pointless. Why you just edited?

Comment: @ReubenPereira: What you have in your comment is correct, but you lose the inequality if you drop $|a_{n+1}|$ as my example shows.

Comment: @kLEIN What are you talking about? And what do you mean with *"Why you just edited?"*?

Comment: @Clayton Thanks alot, I think i get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-a_{n+1}|<\infty$, we can say that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty|a_n-a_{n+1}|<\varepsilon.$$ Now, by definition, a sequence is Cauchy if given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $|a_k-a_m|<\varepsilon$ for $k,m>N$. But note that $$|a_k-a_m|\leq\sum_{n=k}^m|a_n-a_{n+1}|\leq\sum_{n=k}^\infty|a_n-a_{n+1}|<\varepsilon.$$ Thus, you have a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: For $m <n$ we have

$$\left|a_n-a_m  \right| \leq \left|a_n-a_{n-1}  \right|+\left|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}  \right|+..+\left|a_{m+1}-a_m  \right|=s_n-s_{m-1}$$

where $s_n$ is the partial sum of your series.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: @MattN. For the record, if you made $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<b_n$ for some summable $b_n$, then you could argue $a_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Why summable? Letting $b_n = 1/n$ one could argue that $a_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: @MattN. No. Say $m<n$, you'd make $$|a_m-a_n|\leq |a_m-a_{m+1}|+|a_{m+1}-a_{m+2}|+\cdots+|a_{n-1}-a_n|=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |a_{k}-a_{k+1}|<\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}b_k$$ Since $b_k$ is summable, you get $<\epsilon$ at the end for $n,m>N$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Sorry, I read $|a_m - a_n|<b_n$ and assumed $m \geq n$.

Comment: Now I agree with you. Thanks for the comment!